# combining date and time and changing it to GMT

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have read many answers for combining date and time and nothing worked so far. I am working in Oracle SQL developer version 3.1.06 and I am trying to combine date and time stamps together. Date is in format dd-mmm-yy. And time is in the following 3 formats-
1. 0348A-- meaning 3:48 am
2. 03:48:00
3. 228 -- meaning minutes from midnight, calculated as (3*60)+48.

And for all these timestamps, I want a query that gets me to this format --
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss . 
I can change the dates and times to string and attach them, but then when I work in powerpivot I am not able to change them to the required format. So, I want to do it in the query itself.

I have already tried something like this-
1. CAST(deptdt as DATETIME)+CAST(time as DATETIME)
2. CAST(depdt AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (depdt - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND) AS DATETIME

Please help!!

Comment: You shouldn't tag your question with sql server when you are working with Oracle. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Is it actually Oracle? You're using several things that aren't valid in Oracle SQL in your attempts, without saying what they did. Why are you storing thse values as strings in the first place; and why three time formats?

Comment: I apologize Sean Lange. I did not know that.

Comment: @AlexPoole In my understanding, its called Oracle SQL Developer DWHP. And, all I can do here is to write query and pull data. I cannot manipulate anything.

Comment: SQL Developer is a client made by Oracle, but it can connect to other database servers. It isn't clear if the syntax you showed is working for you - if it is then it isn't an Oracle DB. Dates a d times are something that vary a lot. You need to establish which kind of database you are connecting to.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you Alex. The syntax wasn;t working there.